# MYSQL insert internal work

Tags: mysql

Assume I have the following table

```
create table MyTable
(
    id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    data varchar(4) not null
);
```

Can anybody explain to me the exact steps that MYSQL server internally executes when I insert an entry from a client like this

```
insert into MyTable (data) values ("ABCD");
```

For example:
(parse query - check privileges - ........ - etc)

I want to know the exact work that MYSQL server do from the moment I send the query from the client to the moment when the data is stored successfully and every thing is okay.

## Edit:

I want to know the steps in the two storage engines : MYISAM - InnoDB

Thanks

Comment: If you want to know this because of pure interest, why don't you read the source code? If there's another reason behind this - why don't you explain the real problem you're having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is the source code.
It's here https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server

After some clarifications, here is a (very minimal) idea of what MySQL (or another database) must do beyond storing a value to a file.
A (MySQL) database has to have ACID transactions, and so must make many strong guarantees that a file does not.

It must ensure:

- Atomicity
- Consistency
- Isolation
- Durability

Further, in most practical cases it must maintain at least one index, which a file does not.

ACID and index maintenance are the work that is done which takes time beyond appending to a flat file.

Comment: Ah, so you don't want what you asked for, which is "the exact work that MYSQL server do from the moment I send the query from the client to the moment when the data is stored successfully".

Comment: @johnsamir - basically you want someone to do work for you for free, is that correct?

Comment: I just want to figure out why inserting data in MYSQL DB takes a relatively long time than inserting this data in a regular binary file . Sorry for incompleteness in my question.

Comment: @egyptian_M totally fine. And what you have just asked me is a completely different question and adds important details to what you asked before. A MySQL database has to have ACID transactions, and so must make many strong guarantees that a file does not. Further, it must maintain an index, which file does not. That work takes time. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)

Comment: Okay Thanks , This is a helpful start

Comment: @egyptian_M: Mainly it ensures the data is written to disk (flushed) at every operation, while disk operations will use memory mapped I/O. You can allow a database to do this as well using ```innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0```. Source: http://tqdev.com/2016-trading-durability-for-performance-without-nosql